# GWT client RPC request serialize

Tags: gwt, client, request, rpc, serialization

I would like to know which is the Generator used by GWT compiler to
create the javascript code that serialize the request on a RPC.

Where this string is created:

```
5|0|6|http://localhost:8080/GWT/gwtgenerator|31DA33B437409DA8B9736360E3F8701D|com.gwt.genetator.client.GreetingService|greetServer|java.lang.String/2004016611|GWT User|1|2|3|4|1|5|6|
```

Thanks

JuDaC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamWriter
```